# Copy large Datatable into MS Access table C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datatable

I wrote the following code in order to copy a DataTable content into a MS Access table. 
The problem is that the data set is very huge, it takes a long time (more than 10mns), and stops when the file reaches 2GB. I know entire set of data is about 785Mo in RAM for about 820000 rows.

```
public static bool InsertmyDataTableDAO(string filePathName, DataTable myDataTable)
    {
        string connectionString = string.Format(ConnectionParameters.MsAccessConnectionStringOledb, filePathName);
        DBEngine dbEngine = new DBEngine();
        Database db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(filePathName);

        db.Execute("DELETE FROM " + myDataTable.TableName);

        Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset(myDataTable.TableName);
        Field[] tableFields = new Field[myDataTable.Columns.Count];


        foreach(DataColumn column in myDataTable.Columns)
        {
            tableFields[column.Ordinal] = rs.Fields[column.ColumnName];
        }

        foreach(DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            rs.AddNew();
            foreach(DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
            {
                tableFields[col.Ordinal].Value = row[col.Ordinal];
            }

            rs.Update();
        }

        rs.Close();
        db.Close();

        return true;
    }
```

Is there a faster way to copy data set from datatable to MS Access DB?

Comment: [This article has information about the limits of Microsoft Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c) database files and objects. In most cases **when a database exceeds the following limits it might be an indication of a design issue**.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is a better way to proceed and it's the purpose of my question. How would you do if you were to copy a datatable into a ms Access table?

Comment: As you do. But the hard limit of an Access file is 2GB. Use _SQL Server Express_ or similar.

Answer (score 3):

The max db size for access is 2GB, you can't bypass this limit :
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using a DELETE statement to remove the rows beforehand.  DELETE doesn't necessarily recover free space.  Here's what I'd do...

1. Use your existing code to delete the data in the table.
2. Next, use Microsoft.Interop.Access to compact/repair the database
3. Finally, run your above code to insert the DataTable.

I'd also add that you could probably use Microsoft.Interop.Access to import the datatable too...  Perhaps save it to a CSV file first... then import it that way rather than using INSERT statements.

Comment: Thanks Douglas.kirschman. The DELETE statement is just for safety. The table is supposed to be empty.  I tried the csv method but it fails because there are too much rows. I'll try Interop.Access as suggested

Comment: For Manual testing, just use Access to open that data file, and do a C+R, and then exit and run your code. Also, 800,000 rows is not that much. You should be able to do that many rows in about 1-2 minutes tops. (and your code looks ok).

Comment: My file was huge because I was making a mistake when creating my db. I used CHAR(50) for all the string fields, instead of VARCHAR. Now my file is 360MB but it still takes 17mns to perform the copy (820000 rows * 43 columns). So I still wonder if there's a faster way to proceed. Thanks for your help